# Using international characters in React Native

Tags: react-native, unicode

I have the following international text in my react native app:

```
<Text>ᚘᚘᚘ</Text>
```

However, a blank line is displayed to my screen where the text should go. I have tried for other international characters as well and it is the same result.

I am using notepad++ and making sure that encoding is set to UTF-8. If I use console.log("ᚘᚘᚘ") it displays to the console just fine. Do I specifically need to embed a particular unicode font in my React Native project for it to work correctly? Or what should I be doing so that it displays my text correctly?

On further investigation I am using a Samsung Galaxy S2 for testing purposes. It does not seem to handle unicode characters in all applications, so I think my app will not work in older devices unless I specifically embed a Unicode font. Am I correct in my thinking?

Comment: works fine for me. Can you replicate it on https://snack.expo.io/?

Comment: I am not using expo. I am thinking maybe it is because I am using an older android device: Samsung Galaxy S2 to test it out on. It doesn't seem to handle unicode fonts in some applications.

Comment: for me international characters are not displaying in React-native application. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @KartiikeyaBaleneni I posted an answer for you below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found to this was to add a custom font. This link explains how to use a custom font: https://blog.bam.tech/developper-news/add-a-custom-font-to-your-react-native-app . The font I used is called GNU FreeFont located here: https://www.gnu.org/software/freefont/

Comment: For me  REST response in foreign language are not displaying. Rest of the normal foreign alerts working fine. can you help me to implement only for FETCH CALLS.

Comment: @KartiikeyaBaleneni Are you able to verify that the sending script is sending the data correctly and that they have the correct file encoding?

Comment: I'm even passing 'charset'- 'utf-8' for request headers.

Comment: @KartiikeyaBaleneni If you do a console.log on the data you are receiving do you see the proper text?

Comment: No. I'm receiving broken text in console too. what may be issue?

Comment: My guess is that it's something on the remote system that is the problem. You should post your own question about it and then place a link here.

Comment: My question link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51168982/fetch-encoding-issue-react-native.     tnx