# Fetch Encoding issue - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, fetch

While parsing fetch response, it can't able to parse special characters in response.

Please find alert response where special characters are breaking.

[image]

While hitting request in postman, this is the response message.

[image]

Here is my fetch request

```
fetch(restUrl, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'x-nanobnk-apikey': urls.APIKey,
                    // 'x-nanobnk-auth': this.token,
                    'Accept-Language': this.state.stLang,
                    'Accept': '*/*',
                    'charset': 'utf-8',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(objReq)
            })
        )
            // .then(ApiUtils.checkStatus)
            .then(response => {

                if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                    return response.text()
                }
                else {
                    return response.json()
                }
            }
            )
            .then(responseJson => {
                let obj = responseJson;
                if (responseJson != null && responseJson != undefined) {
                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('error') || obj.hasOwnProperty('errorType')) {
                        // failure scenario
                        console.log(responseJson + "from failure scenario");
                        this.setState({ btnDisableBool: false });
                        alert(obj.message);

                    }
                    else {
                        // Success response

                        }

                }
                else {
                    this.setState({ btnDisableBool: false });
                    alert(i18n.t('unable'));
                }
            })
```

as you can see I'm even passing 'Charset'-'utf-8' header parameter.

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: is your display page (the one showing the message) set correctly to display utf-8 chars ?

Comment: how to set that? @Gabriele Petrioli

Comment: Have you added the `<meta charset="utf-8" />` to the html page which loads your scripts/app ?

Comment: Mine is an mobile application built on react native. can we enable meta charset ?

Comment: What mobile device are you testing on? Are you able to test on a newer device or iPhone?

Comment: I'm testing on both android and IOS devices and simulators

Comment: Are you able to create a log file on the other server side to save a copy of the text that is being sent back to your app? This will help you determine whether the issue is actually server side or client side.